# Using .do files with ModelSim (10.3a)

Tags: macros, vhdl, modelsim

*Here is the (brief) context for my question :*

I am working in **VHDL** (with Microsemi's Design Suite, Libero) and I use **ModelSim** to simulate my work. To that extent, I use a classic VDHL TestBench and, to save time, a **.do** Macro File.
This .do Macro file contains very basic commands such as "restart" or deleting/adding waves.

Even if I'm not expecting much from such a file, it would be convenient for me to include in it more actions, that I have to perform by hand with the Graphical Interface like, something that I use quite a lot : combining signals into a custom bus. This action is very simple to do in Modelsim's graphical interface but I can't find anywhere how to perform this in a .do Macro File.

*So my question is :*

Where can I find some good documentation regarding these ModelSim's .do Macro Files?
Or am I missing the point about the use of these files? Is it relevant to use it in sich a way?

*I really hate to ask this kind of question here but, even if I was able to find some info here and there on various websites, I found nothing significant. I have been through quit a lot of ModelSim help documents or user guides but it almost always focused on the graphical interface.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a command reference manual for your ModelSim version here:
[www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/134097-modelsim-command-reference-manual-v10-3a](http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/134097-modelsim-command-reference-manual-v10-3a).

You should also be able to find this and other documentation in ModelSim under "Help" > "PE Documentation - PDF Bookcase" (substitute 'PE' for the edition you are running).

You should see all the usual commands like 'add wave'. These can be used in .do files, and TCL script files.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I really don't know how I managed to not find it, but thanks a bunch !

Comment: It doesn't help that you don't get any google search results from the ModelSim website itself. I think I was referred to this by support at some point. I just remembered that all the documentation is bundled with the install, so I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dividers to seperate signals with 
`add wave -divider -heigth 10 $DIVIDER_NAME`
and also if you want to expand-collapse signals, you can add signal with
`add wave -group $GROUP_NAME -position end ....`

http://users.utcluj.ro/~baruch/resources/ModelSim/modelsim_user.pdf page 306

Comment: This helps for my bus/signal issue thanks!
However, I'm looking for some more exhaustive documentation on this. (And I think scary_jeff found the one).